# Publish post with image doesn't work in page

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I got the page access token as mentioned below. When I tried to make a post with image to Facebook page. It used my user account posts to the facebook page, instead of page itself post.

**Get Page Access Token**

```
$facebook.api("/" + page_id + "?fields=access_token").then(function(response){
  auth_token = response.access_token;
});
```

**Post to Page**

```
$facebook.api("/"+page_id+"/photos","POST",
{
  caption: body,
  url: "http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg",
}).then(function(response){
  $scope.result = response;
});
```

**Problem**: It used my user account to post. How can I let my page to post instead?

Comment: Use a page access token

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Page Token includes the `publish_pages` permission, and add the Page Token in your API call:

```
$facebook.api('/' + page_id + '/photos', 'POST', {
    caption: body,
    url: "http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg",
    access_token: auth_token
}).then(function(response){
    $scope.result = response;
});
```

You can debug your Token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/